# cellForRowAtIndexPath called no. of times that array count return,Why?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I am facing new problem.In my app, i am getting data by using NSXmlParser.

After parsing data , i am creating UITableview manually.

Here is my code,

```
 -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:self.cData];
parser.delegate = self ;
[parser parse];
tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tableView.dataSource = self;
tableView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

This is my delegates methods

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
    return 1;
  }
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
    return eventName.count;
  }
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  }
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
     cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

     }

    for (int i=0; i < eventName.count; i++)
   {
       cell.textLabel.text = [eventName objectAtIndex:i];
       NSLog(@"%@",cell.textLabel.text);
    }
   return cell;
  }
```

Comment: So, Whats your question? and you should not use loop in CellForRowAtIndexPath Method

Comment: it will be called the first time u load the table a Cell for every row has to be created, there's is nothing wrong in it being called event.count times do not use the for loop youu used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking `i` in the `for loop`, remove the `for loop` and look for `indexPath.row` in-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...
    cell.textLabel.text = [eventName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ...
}
```

It will be called as many times as the value returned by-

`-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{}`